# Javascript (front-end) file structure in Node JS + Express application

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am making an application wit this tech stack: Node JS, Express JS, EJS. I am having a hard time organizing my front end javascript code which is increasingly becoming bloated. I am trying to find a solution on how the structure should be. Current file tree:

```
Application
|-- bin
|-- configs
|-- helpers
|-- middleware
|-- models
|-- public
|   |-- images
|   |-- javascripts
|   `-- css
|-- routes
|-- services
|-- uploads
|-- views
|   `-- partials
`-- app.js
```

Now for me the biggest question is how to optimally include and how to work with javascript files (Front-end). Should I be making a main javascript file which includes all the javascript I need (via ES6 modules) and then have it in the layout.ejs file? Or should part of JS be available in .ejs files related to the view?

```
index.js
|-- utils.js
|-- navigation.js
|   |-- registration.js
|   `-- login.js
|-- manageTasks.js
|   |-- create.js
|   |-- update.js
|   `-- delete.js
`-- news.js
    |-- subscribe.js
    `-- read.js
```

Am I not creating too much overhead? For example if I am in news section, I would only care about all javascript except manageTasks.js but it would still be loaded.

Regards,
Rokas